# On a custom UITableViewCell with a button the text disappears sometimes - iOS 7

Tags: uitableview, xamarin.ios, ios7

I've created a custom `UITableViewCell` with a `UIButton` in it. In iOS 6 it behaves as expected all the time. In iOS 7 it looks correct after the view is loaded the first time. But after any `TableView.ReloadData()` the text on the button disappears until I touch the button and swipe away to not trigger the click event.

You can see the described behavior in the movie: http://youtu.be/9SrKfouah7A

ButtonCellNew.cs

```
using System;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Drawing;

namespace B2.Device.iOS
{
    public class ButtonCellNew : UITableViewCell
    {
        private string _reuseIdentifier;
        private bool _eventRegistered;

        public Action<object, EventArgs> ButtonClickedAction; 

        public UIButton Button { get; set; }

        public ButtonCellNew(string reuseIdentifier) : base()
        {
            _reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier;
            Initialize();
        }

        public override string ReuseIdentifier
        {
            get
            {
                return _reuseIdentifier;
            }
        }

        private void Initialize()
        {
            // Cell
            SelectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

            // Button
            Button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
            Button.Frame = Bounds;
            Button.Font = UIFont.BoldSystemFontOfSize(15);
            Button.SetTitleColor(Colors.ButtonTitle, UIControlState.Normal);
            Button.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
            ContentView.AddSubview(Button);
        }

        public override void PrepareForReuse()
        {
            base.PrepareForReuse();

            Button.TitleLabel.Text = string.Empty;
        }

        public void RegisterEvents()
        {
            ButtonClickedAction = null;

            if (!_eventRegistered)
            {
                Button.TouchUpInside += ButtonClicked;
                _eventRegistered = true;
            }
        }

        private void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ButtonClickedAction != null)
                ButtonClickedAction(sender, e);
        }
    }
}
```

MyTableViewController.cs

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
{
    else if (indexPath.Section == (int)SupportTableViewSection.Button && indexPath.Row == (int)SupportTableViewButtonRow.Close)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("buttonCell") as ButtonCellNew;
        if (cell == null)
            cell = new ButtonCellNew("buttonCell");

        cell.Button.SetTitle("Support Einstellungen schliessen", UIControlState.Normal);
        cell.RegisterEvents();
        cell.ButtonClickedAction = ExitSupportSettings;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the `PrepareForReuse` method in your `ButtonCellNew` class.

I had similar issues with it on iOS 7 and I removed it completely. It seems as its behavior has somewhat changed, as it's called by the system right before the cell is returned from the `DequeueReusableCell` method. Apparently, the "new" behavior includes calling the method at some other point also. Or... it's a bug or something.

It's not that important anyway, as Apple only suggests using it for resetting UI-related properties and not content-related properties.

So you can live without:

```
Button.TitleLabel.Text = string.Empty;
```